# How to let non-administrator Windows user install programs specifically allowed by domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow Domain Users to install software on their computers](https://serverfault.com/questions/165013/allow-domain-users-to-install-software-on-their-computers)

Is there a way to let non-administrator users to install programs specifically allowed by the domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your solution here is System center configuration manager which allows you to publish applications available for install on the domain. The user can then go to their control panel > advertised programs and just select for a software package to be installed.

Comment: or just active directory - GPO software installation aldo can deal with publicadctions.

Comment: +1 for TomTom. Make that an answer and I'll upvote it in a minute. I appreciate that SCCM has "Publishing" functionality but it's built-in to Group Policy "out of the box".